# Response cache on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: caching, amazon-web-services, nginx

I have an API hosted on Elastic Beanstalk written in Node.js using nginx. I don't need an in-memory cache like ElasticCache provides. I just need the server to cache on disk the response when calls to my API are made. The reason is because the calls in my API make calls to a third-party API and they are expensive. The response from the third-parties are big in terms of file size.

Could you please help me figure out how I'd do it or if it's even possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use beanstalk .config files to configure NGINX caching, see:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html
http://nginx.com/resources/admin-guide/caching/

But it would probably be a better ideia to use CloudFront to cache content on the 50+ edge locations used by this service, thus requests that can be responded by the cache would not even hit your server.